# What’s the most Pythonic way of handling different, mutually-exclusive function inputs?

Tags: python, input

I am trying to find a clean way to handle different, mutually-exclusive function inputs. The idea is that I have a function which returns 4 values (these values are linked through mathematical equations), and when you input one of the 4 values, it returns all the values.

Currently the function works like this:

```
#example relations are simply: b=1+a, c=0.5*a, d=sqrt(a)
def relations(v, vtype="a"):
    if vtype=="a":
        a = v
    elif vtype=="b":
        a = v - 1
    elif vtype=="c":
        a = 2 * v
    elif vtype=="d":
        a = v ** 2

    b = 1 + a
    c = 0.5 * a
    d = a ** 0.5

    return a,b,c,d
```

The user specifies what the input variable is by means of a string vtype, and it returns all the values. It is not possible for the user to input more than one different input value (would be redundant, because all the unknowns can be determined from one input value).

Is there a more clean and pythonic way to do this? Specifying the input variable with a string feels really dirty at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of your current implementation feels dirty?

Comment: Having the user specify the input type as a string through the variable vtype. I mean, come on....

Comment: This is more pythonic than any of the answers so far. The only thing that disturbs, are the magic constants `'a'`, `'b'` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach to avoid many `if`-`elif`s is to build a dictionary of functions:

```
def relations(v, vtype='a'):
    functions = {
        'a': lambda x: x, 'b': lambda x: x-1,
        'c': lambda x: x * 2, 'd': lambda x: x**2
    }

    a = functions[vtype](v)
    b = 1 + a
    c = 0.5 * a
    d = a ** 0.5
    return a,b,c,d
```

*If this function is not a bottleneck* you can avoid using the `lambda`s and simply do:

```
values = {'a': v, 'b': v-1, 'c': v * 2, 'd': v**2}
a = values[vtype]
```

If you don't like the idea of having `vtype` in the function signature you can use a single `**kwargs` argument:

```
def relations(**kwargs):
    if len(kwargs) != 1 or not set('abcd').intersection(kwargs):
        raise ValueError('Invalid parameters')
    vtype, v = kwargs.popitem()
    functions = {
        'a': lambda x: x, 'b': lambda x: x-1,
        'c': lambda x: x * 2, 'd': lambda x: x**2
    }

    a = functions[vtype](v)
    b = 1 + a
    c = 0.5 * a
    d = a ** 0.5
    return a,b,c,d
```

Then call it as:

```
relations(a=...)
relations(b=...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I should have made myself clear in the original post by stating that i didn't like the vtype argument. I agree a suitable solution is kwargs. The lambda's will not work because for some values I have to do a complex mathematical equation to inverse the relations (or even iteration through newton-raphson), so the if-elif structure is not the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use variable keyword arguments:

```
def relations(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        a = kwargs['a']
    elif 'b' in kwargs:
        a = kwargs['b'] - 1
    elif 'c' in kwargs:
        a = kwargs['c'] * 2
    elif 'd' in kwargs:
        a = kwargs['d'] ** 2
    else:
        raise TypeError('missing an argument')

    b = 1 + a
    c = 0.5 * a
    d = a ** 0.5

    return a, b, c, d
```

Then use with named parameters:

```
relations(a=2)
relations(b=4)
relations(c=9)
relations(d=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your vtypes as functions, and pass the function as parameter

```
def a(v):
    return v

def b(v):
    return v-1

def c(v):
    return 2*v

def d(v):
    return v**2

def relations(v, vtype=a):
    value_a = vtype(v)
    value_b = 1 + value_a
    value_c = 0.5 * value_a
    value_d = value_a ** 0.5
    return value_a,value_b,value_c,value_d
```

With that you can get rid of the `if`/`elif` too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
def relations(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if a is not None:
        pass
    elif b is not None:
        a = b - 1
    elif c is not None:
        a = 2 * c
    elif d is not None:
        a = d ** 2
    else:
        raise TypeError('At least one argument needed')

    # your calculations
```

Then you can use the function simply with e.g. `relations(c=10)` or `relations(a=2)`.
So you don't need the `vtype` argument.

The first passed argument is used to calculate `a`. If you call the function with more than one argument only the first will be used and the others will be ignored (e.g. `relations(b=2, c=5)` only `b` will be used and `c` is ignored).

Comment: Don't use `!=` with `None`. Use `is not`: `if a is not None:`.